# Why do withr::with_seed and R.utils::withSeed generate different results when used in async code?

Tags: r, r-future, r-promises

I'm trying to learn async programming using R so that I can implement an app that requires generation of random numbers with specified seeds (*always* with specified seeds). I've been using `R.utils::withSeed` for this, but I know that `withr::with_seed` also exists so I thought I might check that out.

I know random number generation is tricky, so I've been trying to run simple examples to try to understand how things work. I need:

- ...to always get the same random numbers when using the same seed
- ...to get the same random numbers with the same seed *regardless* of whether I'm using the async framework (so I should be able to run the code outside a promise and get the same answer)

In the code below, I define two functions to generate random numbers, settings the seed with either `withr::with_seed` or `R.utils::withSeed`.

- These two functions give me the same answer when run outside the promise.
- These two functions give different answers when run inside the promise.
- The `withr::with_seed` version gives the same answer inside or outside the promise.
- The `R.utils::withSeed` version gives different answers inside or outside the promise.

The answers seem to be consistent across multiple runs, however.

My question is: why? Is this a bug in `R.utils::withSeed`, or am I misunderstanding something?

---

### Code

```
library(future)
library(promises)

plan(multisession)


s0_R = function(seed = 1, n = 1){
  R.utils::withSeed(expr = {
    rnorm(n)
  }, seed = seed)
}

s0_w = function(seed = 1, n = 1){
  withr::with_seed(
     seed = seed,
     code = {
       rnorm(n)
     })
}


s_R = function(seed = 1, n = 1){
  future_promise(
    {
    Sys.sleep(5)
    s0_R(seed, n)
    }, 
    seed = TRUE
  )
} 

s_w = function(seed = 1, n = 1){
  future_promise(
    {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      s0_w(seed, n)
    }, 
    seed = TRUE
  )
} 

s0_R(123) %>%
  paste(" (R.utils::withSeed)\n") %>%
  cat()
# -0.560475646552213  (R.utils::withSeed)

s0_w(123) %>%
  paste(" (withr::with_seed)\n") %>%
  cat()
# -0.560475646552213  (withr::with_seed)

s_R(123) %...>%
  paste(" (async, R.utils::withSeed)\n") %...>%
  cat()

s_w(123) %...>%
  paste(" (async, withr::with_seed)\n") %...>%
  cat()

# Results occur later...
# -0.968592726552943  (async, R.utils::withSeed)
# -0.560475646552213  (async, withr::with_seed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `future` package sets the default RNG kind to L'Ecuyer-CMRG, whereas R's default is Mersenne-Twister. `withr::with_seed` resets the RNG kind to `"default"` (i.e. Mersenne-Twister) unless it is explicitly specified in the `.rng_kind` argument. `R.utils::withSeed`, on the other hand, does not do anything about RNG kind by default, but the RNG kind can be specified using the `...` argument list passed to `set.seed`. In your example, the `s0_R` can be modified as follows to get the same results inside and outside the promise.

```
s0_R = function(seed = 1, n = 1){
  R.utils::withSeed(expr = {
    rnorm(n)
  }, seed = seed, kind = "default")
}
```